# How to set smooth animation with image view and scroll view in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have below code and it's working partially. 
Here is the conditions should be fulfilled.

- Need to swipe the images with dragging (move image with finger when
  dragging). -> Working
- Animation must be smooth -> Working
- Should display the first image when appear -> Not working (It shows
  between second and third images)

Can someone find what am I missing?

```
struct ImageCarousel: View {
    let images: [UIImage]
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var currentIndex = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(images, id: \.self) { image in
                        Image(uiImage: image)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width * CGFloat(images.count), height: geometry.size.height)
            }
            .content.offset(x: offset)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        offset = value.translation.width - CGFloat(currentIndex) * geometry.size.width
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        let dragThreshold = geometry.size.width * 0.2
                        withAnimation {
                            if value.predictedEndTranslation.width < -dragThreshold && currentIndex < images.count - 1 {
                                currentIndex += 1
                                offset = -CGFloat(currentIndex) * geometry.size.width
                            } else if value.predictedEndTranslation.width > dragThreshold && currentIndex > 0 {
                                currentIndex -= 1
                                offset = -CGFloat(currentIndex) * geometry.size.width
                            } else {
                                offset = -CGFloat(currentIndex) * geometry.size.width
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .onAppear {
                offset = CGFloat(currentIndex) * geometry.size.width
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let images = [
        UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "image01"),
        UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "image02"),
        UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "image03"),
        UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "image04")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ImageCarousel(images: images)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated working code if anyone needed.

```
struct ImageCarousel: View {
    let images: [UIImage]
    @State private var currentIndex = 0
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(images, id: \.self) { image in
                        Image(uiImage: image)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                    }
                }
                .offset(x: self.offset)
                .animation(.spring())
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            self.offset = -CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * geometry.size.width + value.translation.width
                        }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            let scrollThreshold = geometry.size.width / 2
                            if value.predictedEndTranslation.width < -scrollThreshold, self.currentIndex < self.images.count - 1 {
                                self.currentIndex += 1
                            } else if value.predictedEndTranslation.width > scrollThreshold, self.currentIndex > 0 {
                                self.currentIndex -= 1
                            }
                            withAnimation {
                                self.offset = -CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * geometry.size.width
                            }
                        }
                )
            }
            .content
            .onAppear {
                self.offset = -CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * geometry.size.width
            }
        }
        Spacer()
        Text("Current Index: \(currentIndex)")
    }
}
```